# Bleachbit Increased Disk Space

Tags: bleachbit

I ran the bleachbit to clean up some of the apt data but there was "free disk space" option enabled which basically took more time to overwrite the data and now the disk space is increased. I dont know where this proxy file is stored which has increased the disk space size.

I don;t know what that file is called and how to delete it. Any idea how to get rid of the file that is used by bleachbit to overwrite previously deleted files?

Comment: Try using Disk Usage Analyser, and see if that can point you in the right direction